# sshd disconnects after unknown syscall

Tags: ssh, kernel, linux-kernel, strace

I'm working on an embedded system (based on a Cortex-A8 CPU) running Linux kernel 4.19, OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h, glibc 2.32, compiled with GCC 10.2 using buildroot.

When a client tries to connect over ssh, the following message is logged to the console, and the client gets disconnected:

```
[  120.954119] audit: type=1326 audit(1599913110.890:2): auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 ses=4294967295 pid=430 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" sig=31 arch=40000028 syscall=407 compat=0 ip=0xb6b5b080 code=0x0
[  120.979667] audit: type=1701 audit(1599913110.910:3): auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 ses=4294967295 pid=430 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" sig=31 res=1
```

After adding the audit package, `ausearch -i` has the following output:

```
type=SECCOMP msg=audit(09/12/20 12:32:13.500:4) : auid=unset uid=sshd gid=sshd ses=unset pid=369 comm=sshd exe=/usr/sbin/sshd sig=SIGSYS arch=armeb syscall=unknown-syscall(407) compat=0 ip=0xb6b3f080 code=kill
----
type=ANOM_ABEND msg=audit(09/12/20 12:32:13.510:5) : auid=unset uid=sshd gid=sshd ses=unset pid=369 comm=sshd exe=/usr/sbin/sshd sig=SIGSYS res=yes
```

When I attach `strace` to the running `sshd` process by running `strace -y -p $(pgrep sshd)`, I get the following output:

```
[pid  2248] write(5<socket:[8970]>, "\0\0\0\16ssh-connection\0\0\0\0", 22 <unfinished ...>
[pid  2244] read(6<socket:[8971]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2248] <... write resumed>)        = 22
[pid  2244] <... read resumed>"\0\0\0\27", 4) = 4
[pid  2248] clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2244] read(6<socket:[8971]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2248] <... clock_gettime resumed>{tv_sec=1838, tv_nsec=947294512}) = 0
[pid  2244] <... read resumed>"\4\0\0\0\16ssh-connection\0\0\0\0", 23) = 23
[pid  2248] clock_nanosleep_time64(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=22439932944646645},  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2244] poll([{fd=6<socket:[8971]>, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7<pipe:[8972]>, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1 <unfinished ...>
[pid  2248] <... clock_nanosleep_time64 resumed> <unfinished ...>) = ?
[pid  2244] <... poll resumed>)         = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLHUP}])
[pid  2244] read(7<pipe:[8972]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2248] +++ killed by SIGSYS +++
```

The issue is also present when I build the system using GCC 9.3 and glibc 2.31.

Is there a way to find out what this unknown syscall would be? Is there something missing from the kernel?

Comment: It looks that 407 is [`clock_nanosleep_time64`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl#L424)

Comment: maybe you should build ssh so it uses the older 32 bit time_t system calls -- your kernel probably doesn't support the new 64 bit calls.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm on the 4.19 branch, where the [table ends with 399](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.155/source/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl), and I can't find clock_nanosleep_time64 there. I got confused as strace logged the call, and I assumed it got the name from the kernel headers.

Comment: Apparently this syscall was added in kernel [v5.1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1/source/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl#L424)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [user414777 commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618737/sshd-disconnects-after-unknown-syscall#comment1157371_618737), the missing syscall is [clock_nanosleep_time64](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl#L424). This was originally added to the kernel on the [5.6 branch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/1/29/355?anz=web) as part of the solution to the [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), and it was backported to every branch starting with 5.1.

The GNU C Library started utilising these 64-bit time functions in v2.31, and the issue I encountered with OpenSSH is mentioned in the [release notes](https://lwn.net/Articles/811275/):

> System call wrappers for time system calls now use the new time64 system calls when available. On 32-bit targets, these wrappers attempt to call the new system calls first and fall back to the older 32-bit time system calls if they are not present.  This may cause issues in environments that cannot handle unsupported system calls gracefully by returning -ENOSYS. Seccomp sandboxes are affected by this issue.

To resolve my issue, I could either:

1. Update the kernel to at least 5.1
2. Downgrade glibc to 2.30
3. Patch glibc 2.32 to omit the time64 system calls
4. Compile OpenSSH with a different sandbox

I decided to go with the kernel update path, as this one seemed to be the most future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and chose the glibc patch approach since our customer insisted on 4.19 LTS kernel

Following patches fixed this issue for my system (glibc 2.32, linux 4.19.178, openssh 8.4p1)

```
diff --git a/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/time64-support.h b/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/time64-support.h
index 8466d37f8f..35bf73f5ee 100644
--- a/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/time64-support.h
+++ b/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/time64-support.h
@@ -54,6 +54,7 @@ extern int __time64_support attribute_hidden;
 static inline bool
 supports_time64 (void)
 {
+  return false;
 #ifdef __ASSUME_TIME64_SYSCALLS
   return true;
 #else
```

and

```
diff --git a/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/arch-syscall.h b/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/arch-syscall.h
index 9352319740..7b73ec2a95 100644
--- a/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/arch-syscall.h
+++ b/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/arch-syscall.h
@@ -29,7 +29,9 @@
 #define __NR_clock_gettime 263
 #define __NR_clock_gettime64 403
 #define __NR_clock_nanosleep 265
+#if 0
 #define __NR_clock_nanosleep_time64 407
+#endif
 #define __NR_clock_settime 262
 #define __NR_clock_settime64 404
 #define __NR_clone 120
```